# How do I get AIC and BIC from a robust linear model using lm_robust (estimatr package)?

Tags: r, lm, robust

I am currently working on the estimation of spatial models and got a problem with my robust SLX model. Technically you do not need to know anything about spatial econometrics, I created all spatial effects manually and wanted to estimate a robust linear regression with the lm_robust command from the `estimatr` package.
This is a plain robust linear estimation and I really don't know why it does not work.

It works for instance for the `rlm` command from the MASS package, but I want to use the lm_robust since it offers the opportunity to choose the type of HAC estimator.

```
library(estimatr)
library(stats4)
lmro <- lm_robust(eq1, data=mydata, se_type = "HC0")
summary(lmro)
AIC(lmro)
BIC(lmro)
```

> Error in UseMethod("logLik") :    no applicable method for 'logLik'
>   applied to an object of class "lm_robust"

I don't get it why the `logLik` cannot be applied to this specific command for robust linear estimation.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: It could be useful if you can provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am using a simple cross-sectional dataset with a Y and several X's. I would send you one, but the only dataset I got right now on my computer is my research set which I am not allowed to publish. Regardless the data I assume the problem occurs with any data being estimated with these commands.

Comment: You don't have to use private data. Create an artificial one or find a public one.

Comment: I do not know how to upload a data file (as I read it is not possible). So when I reproduced my problem plain and simple (creating random numbers in Excel for some Y and multiple X values and copying them), the same problem as described above occured. '''' my_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                      sep = "\t", header=TRUE)

View(my_data)

eq1 <- Y~X1+X2+X3

install.packages("estimatr")
install.packages("stats4")

library(estimatr)
library(stats4)

lmro <- lm_robust(eq1, data=my_data, se_type = "HC0")
summary(lmro)

AIC(lmro)
BIC(lmro) ''''

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi Suren and sorry for my late response. I read under your link that R contains already sample data sets. So I adjusted the code with one of these to obtain the same error as described above. ''''dput(mtcars)
eq1 <- mpg~hp+drat+wt

install.packages("estimatr")
install.packages("MASS")
install.packages("stats4")

library(estimatr)
library(MASS)
library(stats4)

lmro <- lm_robust(eq1, data=mtcars, se_type = "HC0")
summary(lmro)

AIC(lmro)
BIC(lmro)''''